# fetching a specific category / specific person photos using wget

Tags: linux, wget, flickr, picturegallery

I want to gather large picture data base for running an application. I saw wget commands for fetching pictures from websites generally, but not with a specific person's name/folder. I was trying to fetch pictures of a specific person from flicker, like this.

wget -r -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png https://www.flickr.com/search/?q=obama

thought it shows as if something is being fetched, with a lot of folders being created, but the insides are actually empty. no pictures are really being fetched. Am I doing something wrong?

does anybody know how to do this, downloading a specific persons photos from google n flicker sort of websites using wget?

Comment: Google and Flickr have protection against that kind of downloading.

Answer (score -1):

By default, `wget` does not `--span-hosts`. But on Flickr the bitmap files are stored on servers with a different DNS name than www.flickr.com {something with "static" in its name typically}.

You may grep for such URLs in the files, you retrieved during your first run. Then, you shall extend the parameters to `wget` by `--span-hosts` and a corresponding list of directory names via `--include-directories`.

Another alternative is to follow the lines of http://blog.fedora-fr.org/shaiton/post/How-to-download-whole-Flickr-album.